# Libvirt: virsh console - no response

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, console, virtual-console

### Issue

- I have Ubuntu 16 as the host running Ubuntu 14 as a guest (kvm).
- I installed the VM using `virt-install`
- All settings and configuration seems fine

> # virsh list
>   Id Name State
>   -------------------
>   2 myVM running
>   # virsh console myVM
>   Connected to domain myVM
>   Escape character is ^]

and nothing.... the cursor doesn't blink... typing doesn't do anything..... the VM is not responding.

Help!

Comment: `virsh console` connects to the "virtual serial console" of your VM. Is that what you want? Or do you want a virtual screen, which depends on your configuration (vnc or spice)? Or something like terminal connection via ssh? Did you try `virt-viewer myVM`?

Comment: Try virsh vncdisplay myVM

Comment: Check the vnc port and try to connect to the vm with vnc

Comment: @ridgy - yes. I want the serial console. something more in the likes of a terminal connection via ssh. I can't use `virt-viewer` since I have a terminal to the host, and not a GUI interface.

Comment: @StancuMihai - Same thing - no response....

Comment: Did you manage to connect to the vm with vnc but the  vm is somehow unresponsive? If yes, could you please reboot the vm while you are connected with vnc, and check if you see the bios start-up screen, and maybe more info before vm got stuck?

Comment: Did you manage to start a process to listen to the serial console in your guest? Without that there will probably be no response (see e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-serial-console-on-debian-linux/).

Comment: If you have any access to the guest system (maybe through ssh), you can (as root) `cat` some text file to `/dev/ttyS0` (if this is your serial port; see `dmesg | grep ttyS`); this should then be visible in your serial console. If you have no access, you could mount the virtual disk using `guestmount` (have to install `libguestfs-tools`on the host) and modify the files like in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 11):

Just managed to get it to work:

Suppose your virtual domain is `myGuest`, your preferred editor is `vi`, and your guest is installed with `grub2`and uses `systemd`. If the last assumption is not true, you might have a look at [Working with the serial console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console).

First, install `libguestfs-tools`on the host:`sudo apt install libguestfs-tools`. You will need this when working with headless guests.

Second, shut down your guest: `virsh shutdown myGuest`.

Next, mount the virtual disk: `guestmount -g myGuest -i /mnt` (or use any other existing directory as mountpoint). Now in `/mnt` you should be able to see the filesystem of the guest.

With `grub2`and `systemd`, you only have to modify the grub configuration: `vi /mnt/etc/default/grub`, and modify like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,19200n8'
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=19200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

As you will have to run `update-grub`on the guest, for the first start you have to also modify `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Find the default boot menu item and append the console information to the `linux`entry to look similar to

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic root=UUID=76f3e237-d791-4e9d-8ad7-fe5c9165ae55 ro console=ttyS0,19200 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,19200
```

Maybe you need root privileges to mount and edit the files.

Now restart the guest and start the virtual console:

```
virsh start myGuest && virsh console myGuest
```

You should see the kernel log and then a login prompt.
After logging in, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: In the version of `guestmount` I'm using (1.36.13), the options seem to be different (there is no `-g` - instead it's `-d` or `--domain`): `guestmount -d myGuest -i /mnt`